# Google auth buttons in the approval page are appears not enabled in froyo's 2.2 default browser since few days

Tags: cordova, oauth, android-2.2-froyo

I have created an application for managing Google accounts tasks and it worked perfect until a few days when mobile phones with android Froyo can not press the "Cancel" or "Accept" button on the approval page for Google Auth. This happens only in the default Froyo's browser, if we use Firefox there is no problem.

Any idea?
Did any update from Google does not work on Froyo browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons are not enabled from Aug 22nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442171/google-oauth-login-page-cancel-and-accept-buttons-are-not-enabled-from-aug-2)

Google engineer replied the issue. It can be expected to be fixed by the end of the week.

Comment: Today is monday and it's not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem for my app developed using Google OAuth and Google Drive SDK since the last week, lot of users are complaining the 'Accept' button in the browser remains disabled. Please let me know if there is a solution to this
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/ApplicationDetails?productId=1a2c2d85-ebda-47c0-ae7c-d60ba15ca19f

Comment: I didnt find a solution yet, thinking to report it to Microsoft as it is happening with IE browsers in Windows Phone apps

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same issue in http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/woopiti/20e820bf-56a3-4ec5-a839-3cb2886c64b6, apparently the problem is only in the browser of Windows phone 7, Windows phone 8 is working fine.