# Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons are not enabled from Aug 22nd

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth

Google oauth login page buttons are not enabled on Android 2.x browsers. Because accept button is disabled, users cannot login with google. Many users of our service report the issue from Aug 22nd.

It is simple to reproduce the issue.

In android 2.3.3 emulator -> Launch browser -> Go to https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/profile -> click login link.

Other browsers are having same issues:

1. Opera : http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1745272
2. BB10 : [Google OAuth Accept button is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429638/google-oauth-accept-button-is-disabled)

Hey google engineers. Do you have any plan to fix the issue? or workaround?

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue to Google and we are working on it. It can be expected to be fixed by the end of this week.

Answer (score 2):

Is the issue fixed or is there an update? I am still facing the same problem for my app which uses Google OAuth2. Lot of users are complaining and getting bad reviews that they can even login. Any action required from the developer's side? or Is there any work around?